# PHP MySQLi A failed prepared query will kill all future code/queries in the script

Tags: php, mysqli, die

I'm trying to figure out exactly how I should work around this. When I have one MySQLi query fail, it automatically kills the rest of the script. For instance

```
//Pure example code
$data = $mysqli->prepare("somequery");
$data->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
//If the query above fails, the rest of the script doesn't get executed.
```

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how I can stop PHP from killing the script when the query fails. Any ideas? I moved to prepared statements because of the supposed performance and security gains. It'd be a pain to rewrite everything to plan old queries.

Thanks,

Comment: Try catch the exception prone bit?

Comment: Execute method returns true/false value just check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually check for success, rather than blindly executing `$data->execute()` when `data` may be `false`, which will raise an error and abort your script.

From the docs, [`prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)...

> returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

Comment: Also, remember to bind any parameters in the prepared statement using `bind_param` before you execute it

Comment: @SalmanA No, but that's not the issue. The issue is that `false->execute()` will *definitely* raise a fatal "Call to a member function on a non-object" error.

Comment: Wow, the amount of feedback I received is awesome. Thanks for the help everyone. Determining the failure at the prepare level seems to work out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

PHP kills scripts on *fatal* errors. If this line fails:

```
$data = $mysqli->prepare("somequery");
```

PHP will not kill your script but `$data` is set to false. The script will be killed upon the next line:

```
$data->execute();
```

With the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in...
```

First of all, you need to enable `error_reporting` so that you could be able to diagnose the problem (and perhaps figure out the solution) yourself. Secondly, as @meagar mentioned, check for return values of mysqli functions:

```
$data = $mysqli->prepare("somequery");
if($data === false) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
    // dying isn't the most graceful approach by the way
    die();
}
if($data->execute() === false) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
    die();
}
```

Changing from mysql_* to mysqli has nothing to do with your issue. If you were using mysql_* you still need to check the return values from functions. A generic rule: never assume that your queries will always succeed.

Comment: Wouldn't that be "*call to a member function **execute()** on a ...*"? (`prepare` only returns FALSE on error, I don't believe it throws any exceptions)

Comment: @Asad: exactly. I mentioned that script will be killed upon _next line_ which is `$data->execute()`.

Comment: Right, but the error you're describing only occurs if the connection has failed, not if preparation of the query has failed. `$mysqli` is an object regardless, so a call to the `prepare` method should always succeed. I think the error should be "*call to a member function **execute()*** (not prepare) *on a ...*". Sorry if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Whoops, I mentioned the right line but posted the wrong error. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($data = $mysqli->prepare("somequery")) {
// binding
  $data->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
}
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)